# Pyspark, loop through the read.json

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to pyspark and i am trying use pyspark for the below use case but not sure how to achieve it, i want the folder name in S3 location as a column name in my read.json
example:

```
s3 location s3://mylocation/raghu/date/Appname-1/1.json
s3://mylocation/raghu/date/Appname-2/1.json
s3://mylocation/raghu/date/Appname-3/1.json
```

and so on

My read json statement is

```
test = sqlContext.read.json("s3a://mylocation/raghu/*/*/)
```

There are multiple json files under each app name,
I tried with boto in python to extract the app name from S3 location but not able to put that app name in "`test = sqlContext.read.json("s3a://mylocation/raghu/*/App-name/)`" to read json files from each app.

i want something like looping through each app name and read files and i also want the app-name to be present as a column in the table as i am finally writing the data in HDFs based on app-name partitions.

I achieved similar in hive by creating staging table on top of S3 location
`s3://mylocation/raghu/date/Appname-1/1.json` and added a script to alter table and add partitions as app-name, this way i was able to get the app-name in table and use it for dynamic partitioning.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have the same problem now , but small change is I have a path s3://bktname/fldr1/<there are lots of files>. How do I read from spark.read.json command